# I want to load all images from my gallery but my cursor return false when i am calling cursor.moveToFirst()

Tags: android, cursor, mediastore

My Code :

```
    public void loadImageFromStorage(Context context,Activity activity){
    Uri uri=null;
    Uri uriExternal= MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    int colIndexId;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uriExternal,null,null,null,null);
    
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(cursor!=null){
    colIndexId=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    int noOfRows=cursor.getCount();
    boolean isFirstRow=cursor.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(uriExternal,cursor.getLong(colIndexId));
        imageUri.add(uri);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this,imageUri,getContentResolver());
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

}}
```

In my code

cursor.getCount() return 0 and cursor.moveToFirst() return false (it means the table which my cursor is pointed contains 0 rows) . At this point my code is not working fine. I used correct mediastore uri but still i am unable to get images from gallery. I don't know what i am missing here ?
I am facing this problem from the last few days but still i am not able to solve it.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `colIndexId=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    int noOfRows=cursor.getCount();` You have already twice used cursor before you check for null. Please change your code to make it robust. No three times!

Comment: Do not call moveToFirst two times.

Comment: After putting colIndexId=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int noOfRows=cursor.getCount();  these two lines in the if statement(cursor!=null) but still cursor.getCount returns 0 and moveToFirst returns false

Comment: That does not avoid a NullPointerException if cursor==null. And if you think it does then why yet checking for null later?

Comment: this is what i am getting after debugging  cursor={ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@9670}  ,                                                                    noOfRows==0                                                                                                                                 and isFirstRow=false   and in my do while loop  an error is generated             
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 0):

Try next. Take into account that you need to have the read permission: [android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). So, besides having it in your manifest, you need to request to be granted too.

```
public void loadImageFromStorage(final Context context){

    final Uri source = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(source,null,null,null,null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        final int columnId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        final List<Uri> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        do {
            final long mediaId = cursor.getLong(columnId);
            final Uri uri= Uri.withAppendedPath(source, Long.toString(mediaId));
            list.add(uri);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        
        final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, list, context.getContentResolver());
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
    
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PerracoLabs i got it . Here , i was not asking runtime permission to access all images